# Sending an API request to google tag manager server side container

Tags: http, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-tag-manager-server-side

I have implemented server side tagging on my website to track all events. Most of the events are generated by GA4 Event tags in the browser, which are then picked up by the ga4 client in the server container. However for some asynchronous events like `sign_up` and purchase, these have been implemented directly from the API response.

I basically copied what the HTTP request that is coming from the web container to the server container looks like (eg my.domain.com/g/collect?v=2&tid=XYZ&....). when I test my setup, I can see that the the request is coming to the server container correctly and event data is getting generated, and also the ga4 tag I have in the server container is correctly POSTing a call to Google Analytics. My issue - I am not actually receiving this data in Google Analytics.

What is even more strange, when I copy exactly the request my API is sending to the server container and send it via postman instead, it shows in google analytics! What am I missing here?

Edit: Just to note, the only difference I can see is the IP address of the request between postman and our servers. I have disabled the data filters in google analytics but still have the same issue. Maybe there is another reason that specific IP Address is getting blocked?